# How to determine best buffer value in geopandas - geometry?

Tags: python, geometry, geopandas

How do I determine best buffer point to use to merge two geopandas DataFrame? Currently, I am doing to trial/error, is the correct approach? After reading documentations and Q&A forum, seems like the buffer is in m (meters). Example: 0.07, 0.05, 0.5, 1, 0.06 ...etc

```
gdf1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    cmip6, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(cmip6['lon_normalized'], cmip6['lat']))

gdf2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    ground, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(ground['longitude'], ground['latitude']))
gdf2['geometry'] = gdf2.geometry.buffer(0.07) # what is buffer? How to choose a value?
```

Comment: Good reference here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74709468/wrong-points-buffer-using-geopandas/74783942#74783942

Comment: In what way do you want to merge them? If the buffers overlap in some way? You need to add more details

Answer (score 0):

The buffer will be in the same units as the coordinate reference system (CRS) of your dataset. So specifying a buffer in degrees lat/lon probably isn't the best.

You should reproject your data to something more appropriate for cartesian-ish geometry, perform the before, and reproject-back to your original coordinates.

So that's something like:

```py
def projected_buffer(gdf, buffer_crs, buffer_dist):
    original_crs = gdf.crs
    return gdf.to_crs(buffer_crs).buffer(buff_dist).to_crs(original_crs)


points = gpd.points_from_xy(ground['longitude'], ground['latitude'])
gdf2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
  ground,
  geometry=points
).pipe(
  projected_buffer,
  utm_or_stateplane_crs,
  size_of_circle
)
```